# Calculating sum of gradients with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file that contains 4 columns such as:

```
A  B  C  D
1  2  3  4
10 20 30 40
100 200 300 400
.
.
.
```

I can calculate gradient of columns B to D versus A such as following commands:

```
NR>1{print $0,($2-b)/($1-a)}{a=$1;b=$2}' file
```

How can I print sum of gradients as the 5th column in the file? The results should be:

```
A  B  C  D sum
1  2  3  4 1+2+3+4=10
10 20 30 40 (20-2)/(10-1)+(30-3)/(10-1)+(40-4)/(10-1)=9
100 200 300 400 (200-20)/(100-10)+(300-30)/(100-10)+(400-40)/(100-10)=9
.
.
.
```

Comment: apart from the logic you want to apply, I don't agree with your: `1+2+3+4=9`  .. my computer doesn't agree with your result either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR == 1 { print $0, "sum"; next } { if (NR == 2) { sum = $1 + $2 + $3 + $4 } else { t = $1 - a; sum = ($2 - b) / t + ($3 - c) / t + ($4 - d) / t } print $0, sum; a = $1; b = $2; c = $3; d = $4 }' file
```

Output:

```
A  B  C  D sum
1  2  3  4 10
10 20 30 40 9
100 200 300 400 9
```

With `... | column -t`:

```
A    B    C    D    sum
1    2    3    4    10
10   20   30   40   9
100  200  300  400  9
```

Update:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
NR == 1 {
    print $0, "sum"
    next
}
{
    sum = 0
    if (NR == 2) {
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
            sum += $i
    } else {
        t = $1 - a[1]
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i)
            sum += ($i - a[i]) / t
    }
    print $0, sum
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
        a[i] = $i
}
```

Usage:

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Comment: If the number of gradients are more (say 20), how can we use 'for' command?

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the same logic to the first line of numbers as you do to the rest, taking the initial value of each column as 0, you get 9 as the result of the sum (as it was in your question originally). This approach uses a loop to accumulate the sum of the gradient from the second field up to the last one. It uses the fact that on the first time round, the uninitialised values in the array `a` evaluate to 0:

```
awk 'NR==1 { print $0, "sum"; next } 
{
    s = 0
    for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) s += ($i-a[i])/($1-a[1]) # accumulate sum
    for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) a[i] = $i      # fill array to be used for next iteration
    print $0, s
}' file
```

You can pack it all onto one line if you want but remember to separate the statements with semicolons. It's also slightly shorter to only use a single `for` loop with an `if`:

```
awk 'NR==1{print$0,"sum";next}{s=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)if(i>1)s+=($i-a[i])/($1-a[1]);a[i]=$i;print$0,s}' file
```

Output:

```
A  B  C  D sum
1  2  3  4 9
10 20 30 40 9
100 200 300 400 9
```